# Best current OpenVG implementation?

Tags: opengl, openvg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best OpenVG implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401422/best-openvg-implementation)

I am aware this is a duplicate of :
[OpenVG implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401422/best-openvg-implementation)
but the page hasn't been updated in 2 years.

Basically I'm looking for a decently fast implementation of OpenVG that works on top of OpenGL.
Does anyone know of some recent and maintained implementation?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is not the best answer... but you may look at: http://developer.nvidia.com/nv-path-rendering - GPU path rendering from NVidia