# from raspberry pi to Windows platform

Tags: c++, c, windows, raspberry-pi, tablet

I developed an application for Raspberry Pi with C and C++ and the OpenVG graphic library. Because of certain circumstances, I want change the platform from Raspberry Pi to Windows tablets. I don't really want to change a lot of my current program, so I'd be nice to find a way, just to compile it on Windows. Which C/C++ Compiler should I use on Windows, that also supports a graphic library like OpenVG?

Comment: There's a very similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401422/best-openvg-implementation), but it's more subjective and very old.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gcc compiler in windows, so it won't give you much trouble if you haven't used any "*system dependent stuff*" (like System("clear") or something like that) as the compiler is the same (watch out the paths, as the may be different if you are loading files)

In windows, unlike linux, you would probably need an IDE, i like dev-cpp which is old, but light and functional, but there are a lot of free options like code::blocks.

About OpenVG, i don't know how to work with that, but probably you will need to install a library or something on the IDE, but probably any  IDE should be able to work with gcc & OpenVG so probably you won't have to code too much